# If text is deprecated in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath what should I use going forward?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

In my "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method I noticed that Xcode highlights "text" and says it's deprecated.  What should I be using instead of text here?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [appDelegate itemClicked:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] text]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
  [appDelegate itemClicked:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel].text];
```